# Limited group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following database:

```
date, connection_id, connection_status, file_requested
2015,     1234      ,      OK          ,file1
2015,     1234      ,      OK          ,file2
2015,     1235      ,      OK          ,file2
2014,     1236      ,      FAILURE     ,file1
```

My current query gives me the number of distinct connections per date per connection status per file_requested, as such:

```
select date, count(distinct(connection_id)), connection_status, 
file_requested from database group by date, connection_status, file_requested;


date,     count     , connection_status, file_requested
2015,     1         ,      OK          ,file1
2015,     1         ,      OK          ,file2
2014,     1         ,      FAILURE     ,file1
```

However, I also want the number of distinct connections per date per connection overall, as shown below. (I know I could do this in a separate query by simply leaving out the "group by file_requested" - but I don't want that.)

```
date,     count     , connection_status, file_requested
2015,     1         ,      OK          ,file1
2015,     1         ,      OK          ,file2
2014,     1         ,      FAILURE     ,file1
2015,     2         ,      OK          ,  --
2014,     1         ,      FAILURE     ,  --
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way around changing the `group by`. You could achieve what you want with a `union`:

```
(select 1 as sort_column, date, count(distinct connection_id), connection_status, 
file_requested from database group by date, connection_status, file_requested)
union all
(select 2 as sort_column, date, count(distinct connection_id), connection_status, 
'--' as file_requested from database group by date, connection_status)
order by sort_column;
```

`distinct` isn't a function, so no parentheses needed.